# Finding the biggest number among 3, I ran into problems for the last part as bolded

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CurrencyExchange_1 {
 
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input any 3 numbers");
    int firstnumber = sc.nextInt();
    int secondnumber = sc.nextInt();
    int thirdnumber = sc.nextInt();

    //Finding the bigger number
    if (firstnumber > secondnumber);
    if (firstnumber > thirdnumber ) {
        System.out.println("Biggest number is " +firstnumber);

    } else if (secondnumber > firstnumber);
    if (secondnumber > thirdnumber); {
        System.out.println("Biggest number is " +secondnumber);

    } **else if** (thirdnumber > firstnumber);
    if (thirdnumber > secondnumber); {
        System.out.println("Biggest number is " +thirdnumber);
    }
  }
}
```

For the bolded part, I originally wrote < else > only without the conditions but it was an error. Even with the code as written above, an error prompts for <'else' without 'if'>. I am not too sure where went wrong as when I completely delete the last < "else" > part, the code works perfectly. I was reading answers for other questions that <else {...}> can work perfectly when not all conditions are met but it seems to be incorrect for me. Please pardon my complicated code because I am currently learning the basics and I am required to solve it using what I know currently which is just the comparing part of programming.

Also, is it me or there is a lot of auto-correct going on? Some words keep changing back when I have clearly edited them!

Thank you all for your kindness! I finally understand my errors! Would like to thank each of y'all personally but to prevent clutter, i'm going to write it here!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to find a max of three numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792692/need-to-find-a-max-of-three-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `&&` statement in Java's `if`.

By writing `if(condition1 && condition2)` both condition1 and condition2 must be `true` for the execution to enter the `if`.

Now you can easily rewrite your code to

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CurrencyExchange_1 {
 
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input any 3 numbers");
    int firstnumber = sc.nextInt();
    int secondnumber = sc.nextInt();
    int thirdnumber = sc.nextInt();

    //Finding the bigger number
    if (firstnumber > secondnumber && firstnumer > thirdnumber) {
        System.out.println("Biggest number is " +firstnumber);
    } else if (secondnumber > firstnumber && secondnumber > thirdnumber) {
        System.out.println("Biggest number is " +secondnumber);
    } else
        System.out.println("Biggest number is " +thirdnumber);
    }
  }
}
```

To answer your actual question the reason why you can not use the `else` statement is because you write `if(...); {}` and also `else if(...);` . In java you do not write a line terminator `;` in if statements. Just write `if(...) {logic}`

By writing `if(...);` or `if(...){}`there will be noting to execute if the condition is true hence the `if` statement is useless. There should always be some logic that is to be executed if the condition in the `if` statement is met.

Comment: Thank you! I would need some time to look through!

Comment: "By writing if(...); [...] there will be noting to execute if the condition is true" More precisely, with `if (c); {a}` then `a` will _always_ be executed, regardless of `c`.

Comment: If all these numbers are equal to each other, then "Biggest number is " + thirdnumber.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is having incorrect `if` statements e.g `if (firstnumber > secondnumber);` if this if condition is true the there is no logic to execute.

You can do simply following to what you want to achieve. [See complete working code here](https://ideone.com/0Hvr4Z):

```
int largest = (firstnumber > secondnumber) ?
            (firstnumber > thirdnumber ? firstnumber : thirdnumber) :
            (secondnumber > thirdnumber ? secondnumber : thirdnumber);
```

**UPDATED**
Following the simplify form of above logic using `if-else`:

```
int largest = thirdnumber;
if(firstnumber > secondnumber)
{
    if(firstnumber > thirdnumber)
        largest = firstnumber;
}
else if (secondnumber > thirdnumber)
    largest = secondnumber;
```

Following is the complete code. [See it working here](https://ideone.com/AUAcGP):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try( Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) )
    {
        System.out.print("Input any 3 numbers:");
        int firstnumber = sc.nextInt();
        int secondnumber = sc.nextInt();
        int thirdnumber = sc.nextInt();

        int largest = thirdnumber;
        if(firstnumber > secondnumber)
        {
            if(firstnumber > thirdnumber)
                largest = firstnumber;
        }
        else if (secondnumber > thirdnumber)
            largest = secondnumber;

        System.out.println("Biggest number is: " +largest);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code works I think especially for beginners this can be challenging to understand...

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase your logic as:

```
int maxnumber;

if (firstnumber > secondnumber && firstnumber > thirdnumber) {
    // 1st larger than both 2nd and 3rd
    maxnumber = firstnumber;
}
else if (secondnumber > thirdnumber) {
    // else 1st is NOT largest -> either 2nd or 3rd is largest
    maxnumber = secondnumber;
}
else {
    // if 2nd not largest, then 3rd must be largest
    maxnumber = thirdnumber;
}

System.out.println("Biggest number is " + maxnumber);
```

Comment: OR you can use ternary operator as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you! I would need some time to look through!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use && in your if and elsif statements. Also use this in the last condition :

`else { System.out.println("Biggest number is " +thirdnumber); }`

Comment: Thank you! I would need some time to look through!

Answer (score 1):

As other replies suggested the best course of action would be to rewrite the if clauses merging some conditions with AND (&& ).

In any case you code has two kind of errors.

1. You use the semicolon after some if statements.
   Example:

> `if (firstnumber > secondnumber);`
> The example above is syntactically correct BUT it does not actually change the flow of the program.

2. You need to use more curly braces to group code together.
   A syntactically correct version could be the following:

   ```
    class CurrencyExchange_1 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input any 3 numbers");
        int firstnumber = sc.nextInt();
        int secondnumber = sc.nextInt();
        int thirdnumber = sc.nextInt();

        //Finding the bigger number
        if (firstnumber > secondnumber) {
            if (firstnumber > thirdnumber) {
                System.out.println("Biggest number is " + firstnumber);

            }
        } else {
            if (secondnumber > firstnumber) {
                if (secondnumber > thirdnumber) {
                    System.out.println("Biggest number is " + secondnumber);

                } else {
                    if (thirdnumber > firstnumber) {
                        if (thirdnumber > secondnumber) {
                            System.out.println("Biggest number is " + thirdnumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create a new variable, say `max` and process the numbers as shown below:

```
// Assign firstnumber to a new variable, max
int max = firstnumber;

// Assign secondnumber to max if secondnumber > max. Do the same thing for other
// numbers as well.

if (secondnumber > max)
    max = secondnumber;
if (thirdnumber > max)
    max = thirdnumber;

// Display the value of max
System.out.println("Biggest number is: " + max);
```