# How to compare three boolean values

Tags: java, boolean, syntax-error

Compare three boolean values and display the first one that is true.

Hey guys, I am trying to write a program that compares three boolean values and displays the first true one. I am comparing three words for their length, and it will display the longest. The error that I am getting is that my else tags aren't working. Take a look at the code.

```
//Check which word is bigger
    if (len1 > len2)
        word1bt2 = true;

    if (len2 > len3)
        word2bt3 = true;

    if (len1 > len3)
        word1bt3 = true;

    //Check which word is the longest
    if (word1bt2 == true && word1bt3 == true);
        System.out.println(wor1);
        else if (word2bt3 == true);
        System.out.println(wor2);
        else System.out.println(wor3);
```

I have set boolean values for word1bt2, word2bt3 and word1bt3. In eclipse, I am getting a syntax error under the elses in my code above. Any help would be great!

Comment: `else tags ` What is an else tag?

Comment: you need to add if after 1st else
if(cond){
... code ...} else if (cond2 ){... code ...} else {... code ...}

Also you need to fix your semicolons.

Comment: Here you should find good answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982210/find-the-max-of-3-numbers-in-java-with-different-data-types-basic-java)

Comment: And *please* don’t write `if(xyz==true)`. Just write `if(xyz)`. There’s no point in comparing booleans with `true`. You wouldn’t write `if((len1 > len2) == true)`, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (word1bt2 == true && word1bt3 == true);
```

Is wrong, you need to remove the semicolon:

```
if (word1bt2 == true && word1bt3 == true)
```

Same for the `else`s

---

```
else (word2bt3 == true);
```

Is wrong too, it should be

```
else if (word2bt3 == true)
```

---

**Side note**: boolean values can be used as condition, so your `if` statements should be

```
if (word1bt2 && word1bt3) // The same as if (word1bt2 == true && word1bt3 == true)
```

Comment: Yeah, I caught the `else if` myself in the post. Didn't copy-paste. Thanks, I am new to Java so this site is great for me.

Comment: `if(bool1 && bool2)` should be used. Expressions such as `bool == true` are frowned upon

Comment: @rocketboy Completely forgot that, i updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How to compare three boolean values?

Dont!

If you find yourself needing to compare three variable you may as well cater for any number of variables immediately - there's no point hanging around - do it properly straight away.

```
public String longest(Iterator<String> i) {
  // Walk the iterator.
  String longest = i.hasNext() ? i.next() : null;
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    String next = i.next();
    if (next.length() > longest.length()) {
      longest = next;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

public String longest(Iterable<String> i) {
  // Walk the iterator.
  return longest(i.iterator());
}

public String longest(String... ss) {
  // An array is iterable.
  return longest(ss);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't understand that at all. I am learning at my own pace in which I want to understand everything that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` and change it with brackets `{}`.

```
if (word1bt2 && word1bt3) {
      System.out.println(wor1);
} else if (word2bt3) {
      System.out.println(wor2);
} else {
      System.out.println(wor3);
}
```

Comment: Brackets arent needed in that specific case

Comment: That's right, but in this case the code is easier to be read.

Comment: Also, the `== true` parts are redundant.

Comment: It’s easier to read if you remove all the obsolete `==true` fragments. It’s one thing to see them in a beginner’s question but another to repeat them in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the else blocks: use `{}` insteaad of `()` to enclose instructions...

Remove the  `;` at the first if!!!!! - Quite common mistake, with very puzzling results!

```
//Check which word is the longest
if (word1bt2 == true && word1bt3 == true) { //leave ; and always add bracket!
    System.out.println(wor1);
}
else if(word2bt3 == true)
{
    System.out.println(wor2);
}
else {
    System.out.println(wor3);
}
```

- if you need a condition in an else branch, you have to use if again - plain else won't have such a feature...
- **ALWAYS** use brackets for bodies of if statements, loops, etc!!!
- Be extremely careful **NOT** to use ; in the lines that don't behave well with it:

  - if statements
  - for loops
  - while() {...} loops' while statement

Answer (score 0):

try this, if lenght are equal then s1 is considered as Bigger. Also i have not added null check

```
 public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

            String word1 = "hi";
            String word2 = "Hello";
            String word3 = "Hell";
            String Bigger = null;
            if(word1.length() >= word2.length() && word1.length() >= word3.length() ){
                Bigger = word1;
            }else if(word2.length() >= word1.length() && word2.length() >= word3.length()){
                Bigger = word2;
            }else if(word3.length() >= word2.length() && word3.length() >= word1.length()){
                Bigger = word3;
            }
            System.out.println(Bigger);

        }

    }
```