# Find maximum from multiple double numbers(not an array) in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following values,

```
    double neutrality = 0.9D;
    double happiness = 0.12D;
    double sadness = 0.232D;
    double anger = 0.001D;
    double fear = 0.43D;
```

What is the best way to find the maximum value from the above items. I know how to use if..else statements.

Is Math.max() is the best way? like

```
Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(neutrality,happiness),sadness),anger),fear)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the max of 3 numbers in Java with different data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982210/find-the-max-of-3-numbers-in-java-with-different-data-types)

Comment: In addition to plain Java, it is worth noting that Apache’s NumberUtils provides a max function https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html , so can have ‘result = max(neutrality, happiness, sadness, anger, fear)’

Answer (score 2):

Using stream will be more readability:

```
double max = DoubleStream.of(neutrality, happiness, sadness, anger, fear)
            .max().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code using 3 ways , using https://repl.it/languages/java

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Find max from multiple double numbers(not an array)");

        double neutrality = 0.9D;
        double happiness = 1.12D;
        double sadness = 0.232D;
        double anger = 0.001D;
        double fear = 0.43D;

        System.out.println("The max is: " +
        Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(neutrality,happiness),sadness),anger),fear));

        System.out.println("The max is: " +DoubleStream.of(neutrality, happiness, sadness, anger, fear).max().getAsDouble());

        System.out.println("The max is: " +Collections.max(Arrays.asList(neutrality,happiness,sadness,anger,fear)));
    }
}
```

Result-

```
Find max from multiple double numbers(not an array)
The max is: 1.12
The max is: 1.12
The max is: 1.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the values to an array and then use:

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));
```